# Is there any way to enable the HiDef graphics profile property on a Silverlight 5 3d Web App?

Tags: xna, silverlight

I have an XNA Windows Game that uses the HiDef profile to load complex fbx and obj files. Trying to move it over to a Silverlight 3d Web App, Silverlight seems to only want to use the Reach profile, and I get an error that the Reach profile does not support a sufficient number of primitive draws per call. Is there any way to change to HiDef in Silverlight 5? It is not in the project properties and attempting to change it in mainpage.xaml.cs only gives me the option of setting it to Reach.

Comment: FYI, I did two years of Silverlight (2012-2011) and gave up because it's just too buggy and poorly supported for XNA. You might want to look into another stack.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunatelly no, HiDef profile is only available on [Windows PC and Xbox 360](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff604995.aspx). You can assume `Silverlight 5 == Windows Phone` for the table referenced. [See also](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnhar/archive/2010/03/12/reach-vs-hidef.aspx).